# name of this inequality

Tags: real-analysis

in a paper I found the following inequality let $u:[a,b]\rightarrow R^2$ a function and $f_1,f_2:R^3\rightarrow R^3$ vectorfields and $c:[a,b]\rightarrow R^3$ a curve

then

$\int^{b}_{a}\left\|  \sum^{2}_{i=1}u_{i}(t)f_{i}(c(t))\right\|dt
\leq \int^{b}_{a}\sqrt{\sum^{2}_{i=1}\left\|f_{i}(c(t))^{2}\right\|}\cdot\sqrt{\sum^{2}_{i=1}\left|u_{i}(t)\right|^{2}}dt
$

It reminded me of Hölder or Cauchy but it is not. Can someone state the correct name or give hints for a proof?

Comment: This is just Cauchy-Schwarz /Holder inequality for the sum followed by an integration from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: are you sure? what about the fact that $u_i$ is scalar but $P_i$ is a vector?